# Is it Possible to use pyAutoGui and Dim the Screen in Windows

Tags: python, windows, operating-system, pyautogui

I am running an application that uses `pyautogui.moveTo()` and `pyautogui.click()` for a long period of time (an hour+).  To decrease the battery drain on my laptop, I'd ideally want the screen to turn off in this period, but because the autogui functions mimic using the mouse, the computer will not turn the screen off.  I'm using Windows 10, and I'm not sure if I could use some functions from PyWin32 or WMI as demonstrated in this post, because the screen will brighten again when the mouse moves each time.

Having the laptop turning off and on the screen repeatedly doesn't seem like it would save too much power, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is what you want but many to all laptops have a brightness setting and windows devices definitely do. This should save some power on your device.

Comment: I edited my question to make it clear that I don't just want the screen dim partially but completely and for the laptop to turn off the screen.  As far as I know my laptop doesn't have that functionality built in